# mysql subquery multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `bus_stops` containing route id's for buses with bus stops like below:

```
 sl_no     route_id                    stop_name
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1          1234                       stop1
  2          1234                       stop2
  3          1235                       stop7
  4          1235                       stop8
  5          5678                       stop1
  6          5678                       stop2
```

I want a route_id that contains both stop1 and stop2 (for stop1 as From station and stop2 as To station I would like to get 1234 but not for "stop2 as From Staion" and "stop1 as To Station").

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT route_id FROM bus_stops AS myAlias
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM bus_stops WHERE route_id = myAlias.route_id AND stops = 'stop1' )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM bus_stops WHERE route_id = myAlias.route_id AND stops = 'stop2' )
```

But it returns route_id for  "stop1 as From station and stop2 as To station" and  "stop2 as From Staion and stop1 as To Station"

Comment: The table structure provided does not make mention of "from" and "to" stations, yet you have claimed that your problem with your existing query is that *it returns route_id for "stop1 as From station and stop2 as To station" and "stop2 as From Staion and stop1 as To Station"*. How are you distinguishing between "from" and "to" stations?

Comment: @Mark i think he uses `sl_no` so the stops are in order : 1,2,3 ... at least this is what i assumed

Comment: Yes am using sl_no for ordering...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your requirements correctly you can try this:

```
SELECT
    route_id
FROM 
    bus_stops
WHERE
    stop_name IN ('stop1','stop2')
GROUP BY
    route_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

**UPDATE:** and to get from and to in the order you want:

```
SELECT
    tmp.route_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(tmp.smin = bs.sl_no AND bs.stop_name = 'stop1','from stop1','') SEPARATOR '') as bfrom,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(tmp.smax = bs.sl_no AND bs.stop_name = 'stop2','to stop2','') SEPARATOR '') as bto
FROM (
    SELECT
        route_id,
        MIN(sl_no) as smin,
        MAX(sl_no) as smax
    FROM 
        bus_stops
    WHERE
        stop_name IN ('stop1','stop2')
    GROUP BY
        route_id
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) = 2
) as tmp
INNER JOIN bus_stops bs
    ON bs.route_id = tmp.route_id
GROUP BY
    tmp.route_id
HAVING
    bfrom <> ''
    AND bto <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it using a JOIN, to get routes where the to stop is after the from stop (ie, the to stop has a larger sl_no than the from stop):-

```
SELECT a.route_id, a.stop_name, b.stop_name
FROM bus_stops a
INNER JOIN bus_stops b 
ON a.route_id = b.route_id
AND a.stop_name = 'stop1'
AND b.stop_name = 'stop2'
AND a.sl_no < b.sl_no
```